# What is this wall bulge?

Tags: drywall, walls, plaster, damage

I would love to identify what this bulge is on an interior staircase wall (leading to exterior, on ground level)

Is it a cause for concern or just shoddy workmanship?

Thank you! [image]

Comment: Hopefully someones first job(and the last).

Comment: But is it a serious structural thing (wall  sinking etc) or just bad plastering?? I am new to all this!

Comment: Structural should be showing good size cracks, that just looks like lumpy plaster.

Comment: I suppose that’s good news of sorts 

Comment: It looks like there may be a moisture problem.

Comment: I had a basement wall that bubbled out like that. It seemed to be some kind of effervescence or something. That isn't concrete is it?

Comment: No it’s not concrete